# OpenCV: Threshold and Invert an image

Tags: c++, opencv, cinder

I'm trying to threshold and invert an image with Cinder OpenCV block.
In openFrameworks I would use something like that:

```
someImage.threshold(230, true);
```

...where true is the parameter to specify to threshold and invert.

In Cinder I'm trying the following:

```
cv::threshold (input, threshNear, 230, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

... that doesn't work, or

```
cv::threshold (input, threshNear, 100, 255, CV_8U);
cv::invert ( threshNear,  threshNearInverted);
```

...that produces and error and let the program stuck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: cv::invert is a *Matrix* inversion, not the color-inversion you probably wanted.

Comment: also, please supply the *exact* error for any of your cases.

Comment: @berak thanks for your comments about the cv::invert - and the vote down :) I've actually found out that the CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV param is the way to go, but the result was misleading due to the value I was using (see my own answer). I will investigate more about this value issue, unfortunately the lack of docs in cinder sometime is a bit overwhelming for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok,
after more testing I've realized that actually the way to go is

```
 cv::threshold (input, threshNear, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

the problem with the code I posted in my question looks like to be related with the threshold value I was trying to use (230 on 255). If I use a lower value (like for example 70 on 255) the color inversion actually works.

Comment: since you are basically using opencv: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold

Comment: oh, and [binary_not](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not) is probably what your 'invert' was supposed to do.